# How can I write different events for tablet and desktop

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, dom-events, right-click

As per my specs I have to show `right click menu` in both desktop and tablet.

[image]

I am using same file for both desktop and tablet.So I written the following in `Marionette.js`

code:

```
events:{
 //desktop events
 "contextmenu td":"checkingDeviceType",
 "contextmenu input":"checkingDeviceType",
 //tablet events
 "mousedown.LongTouch td":"checkingDeviceType",
 "mousedown.LongTouch input":"checkingDeviceType",
},
checkingDeviceType:function(event){
    var windowWidth=window.screen.width,self=this;
    if (windowWidth>1024) {
        //desktop view
        this.renderingfRightClickFeature(event);
    }else{
        //tablet view
        setTimeout(function(){
                self.renderingfRightClickFeature(event)},
                1000
        );
    };
},
renderingfRightClickFeature:function(event){
     //logic is here
     console.log("Right click menu code comes here");
   }
```

As per specs,In `desktop` If user press right click then `menu` will come.In same way in `tablet` in `long press` event right click menu will appear.

What I am facing problem:

Even If I click(left click) in desktop `right click menu` appearing.That means `mousedown.LongTouch` event firing.But it shouldn't fire in desktop.

I hope you understand what's my problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,I used `taphold` event instead of `mousedown.LongTouch`. Now it's working fine.